No such partition error in GRUB
After installing Ubuntu, everything was okay. But when I powered off my pc, I get no such partition error.
When using ls command in GRUB and checking drives, none are readable.
I fixed it by using Windows Boot Manager instead.
I can boot into Ubuntu without any problems. It's on a separate SSD.
Files are not broken or etc. It's just GRUB being stupid I guess.

have you tried purging grub and reinstalling it?
